# asp.net, c# with mappath

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 10 rows like (`E:\\DocumentManager\\Upload\\rzgtlxvmuolmhej4ibvyif2o.pdf`) already in the database. so I have dataset to pick it up, and now I want to know
how to display/show on  the browser
 (`E:\\DocumentManager\\Upload\\rzgtlxvmuolmhej4ibvyif2o.pdf`) on the web using aspx/c# code behind.

Answer (score 0):

MapPath is for relative paths

For an absolute path, simply use the path string as is

`Response.WriteFile("E:\...");`

Comment: I have the following codes by using Response.WriteFile but get alert saying 'the directory is invalid'. of course, it verify the pdf file is existed.

Comment: Are you certain that the file exists on the web server? (and not elsewhere)

Comment: It alerts 'The directory is invalid' of course I already verified the file is there.

Comment: make sure ASP.NET/IIS has the appropriate permissions to access the file

Comment: make sure ASP.NET/IIS has the appropriate permissions to access the file .. .how can I make sure? And in addition, if I just want to open the (E:\\...file) on the web, and I don't want to add additional virtual directory. is it possible?

Comment: No, that isn't possible - you can't serve files if the web server is not aware of them. To check permissions, go to the directory in questions and check the permissions as you would for any windows folder.